# How to display data in fragment from firebase database using textview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch data from firebase, then retrieve it using `DataSnapshot`.  The data is stored in the database so I tried using `listview` and `textview` to display the data. The problem is failed to retrieved data from database. Class `ProfileFragment.java` is the one used to display data, and data is stored using `UserSignup.java`.

ProfileFragment.java

```
package android.com.part2.ui.profile;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.com.part2.UserProfile;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import android.com.part2.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import static androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Constraints.TAG;

        public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

            private ProfileViewModel profileViewModel;
            private TextView tvUserName;
            private TextView tvPhoneNumber;
            private TextView tvDeliveryAddress;
            private TextView tvUserEmail;
            private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
            private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
            private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
            private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
            private  String userID;
            private ListView mListView;
            private String[] items;
            private View root;

            private UserProfile uInfo;

            public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                                     ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                profileViewModel =
                        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ProfileViewModel.class);
                View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);


                tvUserName = root.findViewById(R.id.namefield);
                tvPhoneNumber = root.findViewById(R.id.phonefield);
                tvUserEmail= root.findViewById(R.id.emailfield);
                tvDeliveryAddress = root.findViewById(R.id.addressfield);
                mListView = (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.listview);


                if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
                    //Go to login
                    //Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getEmail());
                    //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.class));

                } else {
                    userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                }

                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                //databaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        if (user != null) {
                            // User is signed in
                            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                            //Toast.makeText(this,"Successfully signed in",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            // User is signed out
                            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                            //toastMessage("Successfully signed out.");
                        }

                    }
                };

                databaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("UserProfile").child(userID);
                if (user != null){
                    userID = user.getUid();
                    DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");
                    DatabaseReference currentUserRef = usersRef.child(userID);
                    currentUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
                            // whenever data at this location is updated.

                            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                UserProfile uInfo = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
                                System.out.println("Loaded");

                                if (uInfo != null) {

                                    uInfo.setDeliveryAddress(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserProfile.class).getDeliveryAddress());
                                    uInfo.setPhoneNumber(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserProfile.class).getPhoneNumber());
                                    uInfo.setUserEmail(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserProfile.class).getUserEmail());
                                    uInfo.setUserName(ds.child(userID).getValue(UserProfile.class).getUserName());

                                    //display all the information
                                    Log.d(TAG, "showData: addresss: " + uInfo.getDeliveryAddress());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "showData: phone_num: " + uInfo.getPhoneNumber());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "showData: email: " + uInfo.getUserEmail());
                                    Log.d(TAG, "showData: name: " + uInfo.getUserName());

                                    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
                                    array.add(uInfo.getDeliveryAddress());
                                    array.add(uInfo.getPhoneNumber());
                                    array.add(uInfo.getUserEmail());
                                    array.add(uInfo.getUserName());

                                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);

                                    //ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ProfileFragment.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
                                    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                                    //mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , array));


                                    tvUserName.setText(uInfo.getUserName());
                                    tvPhoneNumber.setText(uInfo.getPhoneNumber());
                                    tvUserEmail.setText(uInfo.getUserEmail());
                                    tvDeliveryAddress.setText(uInfo.getDeliveryAddress());
                                }else{
                                    System.out.println("Fail to load");
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            throw databaseError.toException();
                            //Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                        }
                    });
                }//end if

                return root;
            }
}
```

fragment_profile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"></ListView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/picRow"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userpic"
                android:layout_width="97dp"
                android:layout_height="117dp"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/userprofile" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/nameRow"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="@string/nameview"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textSize" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvnamefield"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textSize"
                tools:targetApi="o" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/phoneRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phoneview"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/phoneview"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textSize" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvphonefield"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:autofillHints="012 3456 789"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textSize"
                tools:targetApi="o" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/emailRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emailview"
                android:layout_width="86dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/emailview"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textSize" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvemailfield"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:autofillHints="abc@email.com"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textSize" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/addressRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="114dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addressview"
                android:layout_width="73dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|fill_vertical"
                android:text="@string/delivery_address"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textSize" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addressfield"
                android:layout_width="243dp"
                android:layout_height="93dp"
                android:autofillHints="address, city, state"
                android:ems="10"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:shadowColor="#00817979"
                android:textSize="@dimen/activity_textSize" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/btnrow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="114dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">


        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/helplink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:text="Need Help?"
        android:textColor="#0418FA"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

UserSignup.java

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(deliverAddr)){

        String userId = databaseReference.push().getKey();

        UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile(userId,name,phoneNo,deliverAddr,userEmail, userPass);
        if (userId != null) {
            databaseReference.child(userId).setValue(userProfile);
        }
        etUserName.setText("");
        etPhoneNumber.setText("");
        etDeliveryAddress.setText("");
        etUserEmail.setText("");
        etUserPassword.setText("");

        Toast.makeText(this, "Information Save", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}else{
     Toast.makeText(UserSignup.this,"Please fill in the form",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

UserProfile.java

```
package android.com.part2;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UserProfile {

    protected String userId;
    protected String userName;
    protected String phoneNumber;
    protected String deliveryAddress;
    protected String userEmail;
    protected String etUserPassword ;
    public int starCount = 0;
    public Map<String, Boolean> stars = new HashMap<>();

    public UserProfile(){

    }

    public UserProfile(String userId, String userName, String phoneNumber, String etDeliveryAddress, String etUserEmail, String etUserPassword) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.deliveryAddress = etDeliveryAddress;
        this.userEmail = etUserEmail;
        this.etUserPassword = etUserPassword;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getDeliveryAddress() {
        return deliveryAddress;
    }

    public void setDeliveryAddress(String deliveryAddress) {
        this.deliveryAddress = deliveryAddress;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public String getEtUserPassword() {
        return etUserPassword;
    }

    public void setEtUserPassword(String etUserPassword) {
        this.etUserPassword = etUserPassword;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is an error in your android studio terminal. share that error maybe help more to understand what is the specific problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very inefficient interactive debugger, so you'll have to do a bit more troubleshooting yourself to find the general direction. For example, if you put a breakpoint on the first line inside `onDataChange` and run the app in a debugger, does it ever hit that breakpoint? If so, and you step through the code, does each line do what you expect it to do? Set more breakpoints like that, and see what part of the code doesn't work as you'd expect it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Okay, I checked the logcat, seems the data is not fetch.

Comment: If `currentUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {` is executed, but neither `onDataChange` nor `onCancelled` get called, that typically means there is no connection from the client to the database servers.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You're right, there is no connection from client to database servers. Please tell me if you have any idea on how fix it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have use many other ways to get the current user, but all I get is `user data is null`.

Comment: Do other apps have an internet connection on the same device? If not, there's not much Firebase can do about it. If they do, you might want to [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check the logcat output for signs of what's going on.